# USB broadcast receiver (ACTION_POWER) not working

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to implement a basic receiver for USB connection. Found a reference [here](https://github.com/double-m/easy-usb-tethering/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/marcellomessori/easyusbtethering).

I searched a lot, but can't make it to work...

```java
package com.example.usbtethering;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "USB connected.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.v("AAAAAAAA", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.usbtethering">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.USBTethering">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.USBTethering.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

On emulator, I am changing the following setting:

[image]

I see the status is changing on the phone bar, but my code is not executed.

Any idea what I am missing?

**TL;DR (XY)**

My goal is to enable USB tethering automatically when connected to USB, only if hour is between 8:00-22:00. The idea is to block internet usage outside of the specified hours.

On the phone - **settings, app-store, browsers, Youtube** and **hotspot** are password locked. So the internet can only be used for **Whatsapp**, **waze**, and **USB tethering**. However this currently requires the "administrator" to manually enable/disable USB tethering in settings each time.

So I intend to create this app which I think should be simple, give it permission to change settings:

1. Enable tethering on each USB connection between 8:00 and 22:00.
2. Disable tethering (if enabled) on 22:00.

I have moderate C++/python programming experience, and some Java, but this is my first attempt to Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As part of the Android 8.0 (API level 26) Background Execution Limits,
> apps that target the API level 26 or higher can no longer register
> broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts in their manifest.
> However, several broadcasts are currently exempted from these
> limitations. Apps can continue to register listeners for the following
> broadcasts, no matter what API level the apps target.

So from the ***API > 28*** Version you must register the reciver for that you can use this piece of code in your **Activity** or if you want to listen to the ***Power Connection*** changes in the background use a **Service**

```
IntentFilter ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED");
IntentFilter ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED");
registerReceiver(new MyReceiver(), ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED);
registerReceiver(new MyReceiver(), ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED);
```

I believe you want to use a **Service** this is an example :

First you need to Create a **Service** (PowerSerivce) in the manifest file :

```
<service
        android:name=".PowerService"
        android:stopWithTask="false" />
        <!-- If set to true,
        this service with be automatically stopped when the user remove a task rooted in an activity owned by the application-->
```

And this is the PowerService.java :

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class PowerService extends Service {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        IntentFilter ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED");
        IntentFilter ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED");
        registerReceiver(new MyReceiver(), ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED);
        registerReceiver(new MyReceiver(), ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED);
        Log.d("Service", "onStartCommand: " );
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e("Service", "onDestroy: " );
    }
}
```

And this is MyReciver :

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED")){
            Toast.makeText(context, "CONNECTED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED")){
            Toast.makeText(context, "DISCONNECTED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

And finaly you need to start this **Service** in my case i started it only for API>=26
normally in APIs below 26 you don't need this Service (you can check it by yourself). in this code I started the **PowerService** only for version above API 26

```
 // add this code in your first activity or where you want 
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
     startService(new Intent(this, PowerService.class)):
    }
```

**References :**

- [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)
- [Implicit Broadcast
  Exceptions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions)